# selenium-4.1.1 NoSuchMethodError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-junit, selenium4

In my project we were using selenium 3.14. For upgradation we upgraded to 4.1.1 for using selenium Capabilities. But there is dependency mismatch issues

we are using-

- selenium-api-4.1.1
- selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-chromium-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-edge-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-java-4.1.1
- selenium-remote-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-support-4.1.1

what is the correct dependency we should use with 4.1.1 selenium

`Message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class com.proj.ConfigTestData at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40) at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:26) at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:222) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:210) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:200) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70) at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93) at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:34) ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; at com.proj.ConfigTestData.<init>(ConfigTestData.java:115) ... 36 more`

I tried searching but no solutions found.I made versions of all dependency same that 4.1.1

Comment: Why do you have so many selenium dependencies? It is enough to have `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java`

Comment: It is needed. Also if I only use selenium-java it gives error in EdgeOption that it cannot be resolved